# Bootstrap container layout system bug

Tags: css, sass

As is known, the `.container-` class in Bootstrap 4.x.x and 5-alpha has an bug in intermediate classes.

To give a little more detail,

**The** `container` **class of Bootstrap 5**

```
.container,
.container-fluid,
.container-sm,
.container-md,
.container-lg,
.container-xl,
.container-xxl {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto; }

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container, .container-sm {
    max-width: 540px; } }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md {
    max-width: 720px; } }
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg {
    max-width: 960px; } }
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
    max-width: 1140px; } }
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    max-width: 1440px; } }
```

So for example if I choose the following class

`<div class="container-md"></div>`, the behavior of the width will be as follows.

```
screen             | container
--------------------------------------------------------
768 or up          | 720px
720 < and < 768    | More than 720px and === screen size
720 or down        | Less than 720px and === screen size
```

The expected behavior here is to keep the max-width: 720px value while the screen size decreases from 768 to 720 pixels. However, the current situation causes a jump in width value.

**Below is the scss coding of bootstrap 5.**

```
  // Responsive containers that are 100% wide until a breakpoint
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $container-max-widths {
    .container-#{$breakpoint} {
      @extend .container-fluid;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints) {
      %responsive-container-#{$breakpoint} {
        max-width: $container-max-width;
      }

      // Extend each breakpoint which is smaller or equal to the current breakpoint
      $extend-breakpoint: true;

      @each $name, $width in $grid-breakpoints {
        @if ($extend-breakpoint) {
          .container#{breakpoint-infix($name, $grid-breakpoints)} {
            @extend %responsive-container-#{$breakpoint};
          }

          // Once the current breakpoint is reached, stop extending
          @if ($breakpoint == $name) {
            $extend-breakpoint: false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The part I added to this code is below.

```
@each $name, $width in $container-max-widths 
  {
    @include media-breakpoint-down($name, $grid-breakpoints)
    {
        %responsive-container-down-#{$name} {
            max-width: $width;
        } 
        .container#{breakpoint-infix($name, $grid-breakpoints)} {
            @extend %responsive-container-down-#{$name};
        }
    }
  }
```

The resulting css file is like this.

```
.container,
.container-fluid,
.container-sm,
.container-md,
.container-lg,
.container-xl,
.container-xxl {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto; }

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container, .container-sm {
    max-width: 540px; } }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md {
    max-width: 720px; } }
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg {
    max-width: 960px; } }
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
    max-width: 1140px; } }
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .container, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    max-width: 1440px; } }
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .container-sm {
    max-width: 540px; } }
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .container-md {
    max-width: 720px; } }
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .container-lg {
    max-width: 960px; } }
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  .container-xl {
    max-width: 1140px; } }
@media (max-width: 1599.98px) {
  .container-xxl {
    max-width: 1440px; } }
```

Thus, it is aimed to prevent the bug in between. Can you rate the code?

Comment: What do you mean by rate the code?